# How to prevent removing decimal point when parsing JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

If you do this...

```
var parsed = JSON.parse('{"myNum":0.0}') ;
```

Then when you look at `parsed.myNum`, you just get `0`. (Fair enough.)

If you do `parsed.myNum.toString()`, you get `"0"`.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to turn this into the string `"0.0"`.

Obviously, in real life I don't control the JSON input, I get the JSON from a web service... I want to parse the JSON using the browser's JSON parser, and to be able to recognise the difference between the number values `0` and `0.0`.

Is there any way to do this, short of manually reading the JSON string? That's not really possible in this case, I need to use the browser's native JSON parser, for speed. (This is for a Chrome extension by the way; no need to worry about it working in other browsers.)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have distinct integer and floating point number types.  The language specification says that coercing a number that has no fraction to a string will drop the decimal point.  Use one of the custom formatting methods like the one bensiu suggests.

Comment: What differences does it make? `0` is `0.0` is `0.00000000000`....

Comment: @Felix Kling: Yes, I know 0 is mathematically the same number as 0.0 :) But imagine a situation where a web server serves either 0 or 0.0, depending on how it's stored in the database (as an integer or as a float). And I want to be able to make that distinction in JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, mathematically there is a difference between 0 and 0.0 :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to get the number of digits from `JSON.parse` or `eval`.  Even if IBM's decimal proposal had been adopted by the EcmaScript committee, the number is still going to be parsed to an IEEE 754 float.

Take a look a http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/source/browse/trunk/src/json_sans_eval.js for a simple JSON parser that you can modify to keep precision info.

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer. I'll have a look at that parser.

Answer (score 7):

If 0.0 is not enclosed in quotes in your JSON (i.e. it's a number and not a string), then there's no way to distinguish it from 0, unless you write your own JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

```
... parsed.myNum.toFixed( 1 ) ...
```

where `1` is number of decimal places

Edit: `parsed.myNum` is number, `parsed.myNym.toFixed( 1 )` would be string

Edit2: in this case you need to pass value as string `{"myNum":'0.0'}` and parsed when calculations is needed or detect decimal separator, parsed number, and use decimal separator position when string is needed

Comment: Sorry, I need to be able to *work out* if the number is `0` or `0.0`. (Or `0.00` for that matter.) I want to be able to get the number with the correct number of digits after the decimal point, *exactly as it appears in the JSON string*.

Comment: This is your best bet, but it will still not give you a decimal point for numbers large enough that they are normally displayed in scientific notation.  E.g. `1e30.toFixed(1) === '1e30'`

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter, `00000.00000` is `0` if you try `JSON.parse('{"myNum":0.00001}')` you'll see a value of `{ myNum=0.0001 }` If you really need it to hold the decimal you'll need to keep it a string `JSON.parse('{"myNum":"0.0"}')`

Comment: It does matter when trying to match them both in HTML.