# PHP: how to prevent json_encode rounding number automatically?

Tags: php, json, decimalformat

Having a big problem with json_encode it automatically round off the digits but I need 2 decimal points on every digits.

PHP:

```
<?php
$numbers = [1.00,2.00];

foreach ($numbers as $i => $number) 
{
      $numbers[$i] = number_format($number, 2, '.', null);
}

echo json_encode($numbers,  JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

OUTPUT:
[1,2]

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
[1.00,2.00]

how can I prevent every digits for not rounding off automatically?

> PS: NOT A STRING :)

Comment: Just remove `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` parameter. It will encode your formatted numbers as strings.

Comment: An integer is just a number. It doesn't have a specific number of decimal places. You're formatting your integers to strings which can have any layout you choose, but then specifically encode the resulting strings as numbers again. You get what you're asking the code for. If you need a specific format pass the numbers as formatted strings

Comment: @martynasma then it leads me to having a string.

Comment: @HoboSapiens i update my question. can you provide me a example

Comment: That is a PHP auto change the data type from float to integer, if you need the json output a `1.00` instead of `1`, you can try add `(string)` or `(float)` before `number_format()`, means `(string)number_format()`

Comment: @sa.lva.ge No I can't because what you're doing is perverse. You want a number, your value is 1. That __is__ the numeric value and it is identical to 1.00. If you want that value presented in a specific format you need a string.

Comment: There's absolutely no point in having numbers with extra zero decimals in JSON. You won't be able to read them in JavaScript. So they are just dead-weight there if you keep them as number. Use strings if you want to JSON to carry over number formatting.

Comment: @AllenChak can you provide me a example? thanks

Comment: @Allen `(string)number_format()` is pointless. `number_format` already returns a string, casting it again won't do anything. If `number_format` *didn't* return a string, casting it to one wouldn't help either in preserving formatting, because an `int` or `float` doesn't have formatting and casting to a string wouldn't add any.

Comment: "I need 2 decimal points" -> No you don't. Think hard on _why_ you think you need it.

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520399/how-to-prevent-removing-decimal-point-when-parsing-json

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you are looking for [`JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), available in PHP 5.6.6. Prior versions, you'll need to either convert to string or suck it up and accept that floats and integers are equivalent when there's no fractional value.

```
$numbers = [1.00,2.00];

echo $res = json_encode($numbers,JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION);
```

Comment: There is 0 difference between 1.0 and 1.00. Any code you write to deal with 1.00 will have same results with 1.0, including checking the precision. If you are concerned with output to user, use strings.

Comment: There's also 0 difference between 1.00 and 1, but tell that to the OP... :)

Comment: I *think* that there are minor differences when checking if 1.0 is of type float vs integer (or maybe its when checking if 1 is of type float) that could be relevant. But 1.0 and 1.00 are both strictly equivalent, and its almost certainly the case that trailing zeros are dropped by the compiler after any "double" or "float" bit is set.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> $numbers = [1.00,2.00];
> ```

Here your numbers have already lost their "decimal values". Seriously, try `var_dump` on them right after this line, you won't get `.00` from that either.

Floating point numbers and integers only contain the **numeric value**, formatting is not preserved in any way. It's not a `json_encode` problem, it's a fundamental truth of numeric values in computing.

If you want to preserve formatting you need to use strings all the way through.

Answer (score -1):

You can use your code in this way as follows:

```
<?php
 $numbers = [1.00,2.00];

 foreach ($numbers as $i => $number) 
 {
    $numbers[$i] = number_format($number, 2, '.', null);
 }

  echo $res = json_encode($numbers); // ["1.00","2.00"]
  echo str_replace('"', '', $res); //[1.00,2.00]
 ?>
```

and Your EXPECTED OUTPUT: [1.00,2.00] which is same.

Comment: this is so dangerous because if i had a json with string values like "name: A, "age" : 19.... it will remove also the "" on the string

Comment: Ok. I replied according to your question and expected result.

Comment: If what the OP wants is nonsense then there's no need to bend over backwards to fulfil their wish.