# How to json encode data retrieved from database

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress plugin, I need to retrieve data from the database, before now, I just use the native php mysql_fetch_row()

// This is an extract of the old code.

```
echo "(";
$rows=array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($query))
{
    //echo "My first Rows <br />";
    //print_r($row);
    $rows[]="[".implode(',',$row)."]";

    //echo "The full rows after first implode <br />";
    //$rows[] = $row;
}
echo "[".implode(',', $rows)."]";

    //echo "The full rows after second implode <br />";

    //print json_encode($rows);
echo ");";
```

## Output

```
?([[1409893200000,134.00],[1416808800000,149.00],[1417413600000,155.00],[1417500000000,155.00],[1418277600000,153.85],[1418364000000,153.85]]);
```

Now I'm using the $wpdb object however, I'm stucked at the point of encoding. 
The data retrieved from the database are strings, and when I do json_encode, it encodes the strings, but what I need the output of my json_encode to be are floats.

// This is an extract of the new code.

```
$rows = array();
                            foreach ( $results as $result )
                            {
                                //- json items -
                                 $rows[]= array(
                                                intval($result->time),
                                                $result->value
                                            ); 


                            }
                                                            echo "(";
                            echo json_encode($rows);
                                                            echo ");";`
```

## Output

```
?([[1418338800000,"153.85"],[1435705200000,"165.40"],[1421362800000,"161.03"],[1426460400000,"150.00"],[1416783600000,"149.00"],[1433890800000,"179.50"],[1433804400000,"179.50"]]);
```

This is the challenge, the second value of the arrays are strings, I have tried to convert the strings to float, but they are not returned in 2 decimal places.

This is what I have done.

```
$num1 = "9";

//Using number_format 

echo (float) number_format($num1,2,'.',''); // result is 9 instead of 9.00

//Using Floatval echo floatval("9"); // result is 9 instead of 9.00
```

How can I format the data to a float with 2 decimal places, like this 9.00 ?

Comment: unfortunately, if you want 9.00 you need to leave it as a string, but of course you can convert to a float, calculate new figures and reconvert back to a string using number format when needed rather than worrying about it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
number_format((float) $num1, 2);
```

Comment: I have tried it, number_format returns a string which will still give me [1418338800000,"153.85"] instead of [1418338800000,153.85]

Comment: This is an answer. The author was asking how to convert a number to a float with two decimal points. This is how I have accomplished that in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the row as a hash ... not an array ... then JSON-encode whatever the hash is.  In any case: do not attempt to muck-around with decimal places: by doing so, you alter the values that are being passed.

Comment: How do I fetch the row as a hash using $wpdb object ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my question, after days of searching.

Here is a post that had the same issue, and this is the solution.

```
foreach ( $results as $result )
    {
        //- json items -
        $rows[]= array(
                   $result->time,
                   $result->value
                    ); 
    }
        echo "(";
                 $res = json_encode($rows);
                 echo str_replace('"', '', $res);
        echo ");";
```

// Result

```
?([[1418338800000,1.81],[1435705200000,1.70],[1421362800000,1.65],[1426460400000,2.00],[1433890800000,2.23],[1433804400000,2.23]]);
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30726401/4956378