# Read and write float values from JSON which ends with .0

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have this JSON file:

```
{
  "weight": 12.0,
  "values": [
    23.4,
    16.5,
    16.8,
    5.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0
  ]
}
```

If I trying to read this file and then write it back (using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`)

```
const fs = require('fs')

const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('test.json'))
console.log(json)
fs.writeFile('test2.json', JSON.stringify(json), (error) => {
  if (error) console.log(error) 
})
```

The output file looks like this:

```
{
  "weight": 12,
  "values": [
    23.4,
    16.5,
    16.8,
    5,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ]
}
```

The problem is if float values ends with `.0`.
But I need keep these values as in the original.

**Can I somehow read float value like a string, and then write it like float value**
(even if it ends with `.0`)?

P.S. Node.js v7.7.4

Comment: `5 === 5.0` O.o

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520399/how-to-prevent-removing-decimal-point-when-parsing-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a float in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript)

Comment: JSON only has a Number type. It doesn't distinguish between floats and integers. `0` and `0.0` are identical in JSON.

Answer (score 2):

For each of them you can use the modulus operator (`%`) to determine if it's a whole number, and if so convert it to a string and append `".0"` to the end of it:

```js
json.values.map(v => {
  return v % 1 === 0 ? v + ".0" : v
})
```

```js
var json = {
  "weight": 12.0,
  "values": [
    23.4,
    16.5,
    16.8,
    5.0,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    0.0
  ]
}

var result = json.values.map(v => {
 return v % 1 === 0 ? v + ".0" : v
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Now you have strings instead of numbers. That's less float-like than the original.

Comment: Thank you. Now I need to write into the json float values like floats (not strings). It's the second part of my question.

Comment: @DmitryScaletta you can't. The numeric value 0.0 *is* 0. Enter `0.0` in your JavaScript console and it will output `0`. The only way you can get JavaScript to retain the decimal is if you treat it as a string instead.