# JSONArray(jsonstring) drops decimal if 0

Tags: java, android, json

I have a json string with floating values:
       `{"foo":10.0,"bar":12.005}`
I need to convert it using `JSONObject(jsonstring)` and I need to retain the decimals, but the json array drops them if they are zero. The result looks like
      `{"foo":10,"bar":12.005}`

I expected that i could provide additional parameters to control the data type but according to 
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject
there is no such option. I also searched google and stackoverflow but i cannot find any similar problems.

Comment: You should read parameter as String instead of Double for this scenario.

Comment: please approve the answer if its correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get the number of digits from JSON.parse or eval. Even if IBM's decimal proposal had been adopted by the EcmaScript committee, the number is still going to be parsed to an IEEE 754 float.

Take a look a http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/source/browse/trunk/src/json_sans_eval.js for a simple JSON parser that you can modify to keep precision info.

solution already provided here

[How to prevent removing decimal point when parsing JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520399/how-to-prevent-removing-decimal-point-when-parsing-json)

Answer (score 2):

JSONObject always treats everything as Objects so they must be converted to float by parsing it.

```
     String json = "{\"foo\":10.0}";
     try{
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json); 
            float f = Float.parseFloat(jo.get("foo").toString());
            System.out.println(f);
        }
     catch(Exception e){
            // Some parsing exception occurs
        }
```

Hope this solves the issue.

Also JSONObject supports methods for getting the items in various datatype like double, int, boolean

```
   double d = jo.getDouble("foo");
   System.out.println(d); // gave me 10.0
```

Similarly we have

```
   int i = getInt("name"); // which returns an integer 
   boolean b = getBoolean("name"); // Automatically parses
```

Comment: This doesn't really help, as i need to retain the decimals in the jsonObject to send it to an API which expects this format.

Comment: see @micha the thing is JSON by default supports only these datatypes string, number, boolean, null/empty, object, array. In most cases what we do is parse it to what datatype we require after obtaining it as a string. And the datatype Number which is supported by the JSON can handle fractions and integers as well.  Try reading this https://restfulapi.net/json-data-types/

Comment: @micha I have added few more method that can help you get your job done. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but this is still not helpfull for my case. I don't need to get the value from the jsonObject, rather I need to retain it within the object itself. The accepted answer provides the right explanation and solution, although it's a little overkill for me. Instead I changed my API to handle this issue.

Comment: perfect @micha !

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour.

The DECIMAL field is converted to the JSON NUMBER data type.
This type trims trailing zeros by default.

It's up to the client/receiver of the JSON to decide how many decimal places it needs to show and set the correct display format.

Comment: "This is expected behavior" is not an answer when OP wants a different behavior. You should have posted this as comment instead.

Comment: @ZohaibAmir You need 50 reputation to be able to make comments. And I think it is perfectly fine to remind the OP that JSON is supposed to work that way.

Comment: @guaravuniverse The accepted answer provided some resources plus a solution, so i accepted that. But in the end I let the receiver set the correct format, as you also suggested, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

For the 10.0 it will add value as an integer in JSON, if you want it with decimal then first you need to convert it as a string and then you need to put string value in JSON.

```
val foo = 10.0
val bar = 12.005
val strFoo = foo.toString();
val jsonObject = JSONObject()
jsonObject.put("foo",strFoo)
jsonObject.put("bar", bar)
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess, it's not a problem of JSON array, rather language's type conversion from float to int.

Use something similar to this to format float to string `String.format("%,.2f", val);`

**Edit**

The Workflow will go as follows:

```
if(Math.ceil(val)==val){ //a number with no fractional points

    String str = String.format("%,.2f", val);
}
else //use_the_floating_number_as_usual
```

Comment: This would work but you would have to know number of decimal places before hand, which you hardcoded as .2f

Comment: @ZohaibAmir I answered the question on how can we approach the solution, not the silver bullet solution. Updated my answer though.