# Disable type validation while JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Have String `{"a":100.000}` and I need to parse it as JSON object.
When I run `JSON.parse("{\"a\":100.000}")`, output is `{a: 100}`.

How do I retain the original format of value after parsing it as JSON object?

Comment: It's not possible to have a *number* that retains excess fractional zeroes. Numbers in JavaScript don't have a display formatting associated with them since `100 === 100.0` and `100 === 100.00` and `100 === 100.000` etc they are all *the same number*. JavaScript will display all these as `100` as there is no reason it would add the fractional part. If you want a formatted number, you need to convert it to a string.

Comment: there is no way to keep decimals after JSON.parse. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520399/how-to-prevent-removing-decimal-point-when-parsing-json