# Jquery Mask Plugin removes decimal zeros

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mask, jquery-mask

I am using [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) in my MVC .Net project. In a bootstrap modal a form is shown which contains a field of type currency.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new { @class = "form-control", data_mask = "#,##0.00", data_mask_reverse = "true" })
```

That modal is used to insert or edit records.

When I open the modal to insert, the mask works perfect.

When I open the modal to edit, the data from the currency field should be loaded into the field, but the mask was not applied to the field. To solve that problem, I did the following when opening the modal.

```
$("#Amount").trigger("input");
```

And it worked perfect.

The problem I have is that if when registering an amount of for example `12,345.00` in the field. When I open the modal for editing, the zeros that are decimal are removed, showing in the field the amount `123.45`.

But, if I register `1,234.56`, when I open the modal to edit, the same value `1,234.56` is shown correctly in the field.

What can I do so that when the decimals are zeros, the mask continues to keep them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued to review my problem and found that it is not the mask that is causing it. Apparently the problem occurs from the `$.parseJSON` that the fields of type numbers when converting a value that has zeros as decimals keeps it as a 0.

[How to prevent removing decimal point when parsing JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520399/how-to-prevent-removing-decimal-point-when-parsing-json)

So my quick fix (I don't know if it's the best or the correct one) was to do the following when assigning the value to the field.

```
$("#Amount").val(amountNum.toFixed(2));
```